# Magento Debugging Tools

Tags: magento2, php, debugging, tools

Can Anyone suggest me the best tools for the debugging in the `Magento 2` for free besides X-debugger.

Comment: Which IDE you are using for Magento development?

Comment: I am using PHP Storm.

Comment: if you are using xdebug v2 then upgrade it to v3, its faster than v2

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to activate the debugger.

1. Please follow the [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#integrationWithProduct) instructions

or follow the 2nd option

2. Copy the `phpinfo()` HTML code and paste it to the [X-Debug](https://xdebug.org/wizard) wizard and click on Analyse my phpinfo() output button. This will show you the steps on how to do it.

Please let me know if you have any issues while doing this.

Comment: Actually I am using now debugger, other than that Any other tools which can help in fast debugging

Comment: Debugging is working? now

Comment: Yes, Working. I just want to know If there are any other tools, that can help Magento developers more efficiently.

Comment: @RanaZain, Debugging tools are used to identify and remove the errors or use for some information. Basically, when enabling the `Debugging` any tool that will run slow. There is no way to run fast while debugging. `PHPStorm` supports **XDebug** and **Zend Debugger**. You can configure either to work.

Comment: @RanaZain If the above answer is useful, please mark it as the answer. So that it can be useful to others.

Comment: Actually I am using debugger now, Can you please tell me the name of the extension, that overrides the templates in the magento.

Comment: @RanaZain Not understand, can you post the thread and tag me, I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Matheus Gontijo, an avid Magento enthusiast, has a series of Youtube video detailing debugging techniques:

- [Magento 2 Debugging Tricks - setData, DataObject.php & PHP xDebug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eo8N7e9eEPI)
- [Magento 2 Debugging Tricks - Complex MySQL Queries, fetchAll & PHP xDebug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLf3OwpAFhQ)

You'll also want to be familiar with:

- The Magento [Profiler](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/mage-profiler.html), comes built into Magento 2.
- Alan Storm's [CommerceBug](https://store.pulsestorm.net/l/commerce-bug-three) which at $50 is well worth the price.
- And just knowing [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) in general, it integrates with many IDEs (I use it in VIM and PhpStorm).